# returning null when getting the values of the paramater of create method in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a custom route that accepts parameter. Which is:

```
Route::get('reservation/{id}/create', 
        ['as' => 'reservation.create', 'uses' => 'ReservationController@create'
]);
```

I have this variable protected $student_id. That id is being assigned to the parameter of the create method of ReservationController as seen below:

```
class ReservationController extends Controller
{
    protected $student_id;

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->student_id;
    }

    public function create($id)
    {
        $this->student_id = $id;
        $subjects = Subject::with('sections')->get();

        return view('reservation.form',compact('subjects'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $subject = new Reservation();

        $subject->section_subject_id = $request->sectionSubjectId;

        $subject->student_id = $this->student_id;

        $subject->save();

    }
}
```

When returning the $id parameter on the create method I get the exact id number. I also assigned that $id with the $student_id. But when assigning the $student_id on the store method I get null value. I know that I am doing wrong here, can someone please help me on this.

Okay, so let me add some information: In my url when using the reservation.create route I have this address localhost:8000/reservation/1/create
the number 1 in that url is the student id i want to get and assign to the student_id in my store method.

I also have this form view:

form.blade.php

```
<body>
 @foreach($subjects as $subject)
 @foreach($subject->sections as $section)
   <tr>
   <td>{{ $section->section_code }}</td>
   <td>{{ $subject->subject_code }}</td>
   <td>{{ $subject->subject_description }}</td>
   <td>{{ $section->pivot->schedule }}</td>
   <td>{{ $subject->units }}</td>
   <td>{{ $section->pivot->room_no }}</td>
   <td>
     <button 
        v-on:click="addSubject( {{ $section->pivot->id }} )" 
        class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Add
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
  @endforeach
 </body>
```

At the same time I make us of vue.js and vue-resource

all.js

```
methods:{
    addSubject: function(id){

    this.$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/reservation',   
    data: { sectionSubjectId: id },
    method: 'POST'
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('success');
    },function (response){
        console.log('failed');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: because student_id is null,use
$subject->student_id = $request->id;or $request->student_id or whatever the name you use

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save variable in `$this->student_id` and use it later in another method. This is not how this works. The thing is these methods are used in different HTTP requests, so variable will not be kept.

You should pass this variable with from the `reservation.form` view to the `store()` method.

You can use Request object for that. In a view:

```
<input name="studentId" type="hidden">{{ $studentId }}</input>
```

And in controller:

```
$studentId = $request->get('studentId');
```

Or you can pass it as second parameter if you want to use it in a `store()` method.

```
 public function store(Request $request, $studentId)
 {
     echo $studentId;
```

Comment: Yes, why not? Also, you can use existing code and add `studentId` next to the `sectionSubjectId` and get it from Request object same way as you get `sectionSubjectId`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought for security issues. But forget that. The problem is that passing two parameters on the addSubject method on my form.blade seems not working. What I did was {{ $section->pivot->id, $student_id }}. Am I missing something here?

Comment: okay i got it addSubject( {{ $section->pivot->id}}, {{ $student_id}} ).